# Update UI every 1 second using Timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I have the following code in my application:

```cs
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{
    progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
    {
        stopWatch.Start();
        lblStatus.Text = "We've begun!";
    });

    int c = 0;

    DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;

    foreach (string file in fileList)
    {
        c++;
        csvCreator.createCSV(file);

        progressReporter.ReportProgress(() =>
        {
            //Estimated time remaining
            if (c % 100 == 0)
            {
                TimeSpan timespent = DateTime.Now - starttime;
                int secondsremaining = (int)(timespent.TotalSeconds / c * (total - c));
                TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsremaining);
                lblTimeRemaining.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                t.Hours,
                t.Minutes,
                t.Seconds,
                t.Milliseconds);
            }

            //Progress bar                            
            int percentComplete = (c * 100 / total);
            if ((int)percentComplete <= progressBar.Maximum)
            {
                progressBar.Value = (int)percentComplete;
            }
        }

    });      
}
```

Right now, my code checks for every 100th iteration and updates the UI. I'd prefer to check every second instead to provide a better user experience.

Any ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: Create a timer with an interval of 1s and update the UI every time it ticks. You already know the solution. But your real problem is probably that you have a time consuming task in the main thread. You need that in a background thread and the UI update needs to be invoked onto the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for the specific implementation using the Timer object in the context of my existing code. createCSV is a processor intensive task, but it is indeed running on a background thread and the ProgressReporter class allows me access to the UI thread to update the UI keeping everything nice and fresh.

Comment: Just create a timer, set it's properties, add an event handler and you are good to go. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) object

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if (c%100==0)` , lookup your `stopWatch` : Did it reach 1 sec? If yes-> update ui.

Of course, reset `stopWatch` after each UI update.

That said, be aware that updating UI requires that the message loop runs. If the UI thread in stuck in a file processing loop, you UI won't be updated correctly.